# AJAX based search returning page information

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I found the source of the error but do not know how to fix it. I'm using codeigniter and I'm trying to make a textbox with search results showing under it to help the user find what they are looking for. Think similar to google's search. When I make the AJAX call, it's returning everything on the webpage as well as the search results.

Example of issue: https://gyazo.com/244ae8f3835233a2690512cebd65876d

That textbox within the div should not be there as well as the white space. Using inspect element I realized the white spaces are my links to my CSS and JS pages. Then there's the textbox which is from my view.

I believe the issue lies within my JS.

```
    //Gets the browser specific XmlHttpRequest Object
function getXmlHttpRequestObject() {
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    return new XMLHttpRequest();
  } else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
    return new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  } else {
    alert("Your Browser Sucks!\nIt's about time to upgrade don't you think?");
  }
}

//Our XmlHttpRequest object to get the auto suggest
var searchReq = getXmlHttpRequestObject();

//Called from keyup on the search textbox.
//Starts the AJAX request.
function searchSuggest() {
  if (searchReq.readyState == 4 || searchReq.readyState == 0) {
    var str = encodeURI(document.getElementById('txtSearch').value);
    searchReq.open("GET", '?search=' + str, true);
    searchReq.onreadystatechange = handleSearchSuggest;
    searchReq.send(null);
  }
}

//Mouse over function
function suggestOver(div_value) {
  div_value.className = 'suggest_link_over';
}
//Mouse out function
function suggestOut(div_value) {
  div_value.className = 'suggest_link';
}
//Click function
function setSearch(value) {
  document.getElementById('txtSearch').value = value;
  document.getElementById('search_suggest').innerHTML = '';
}

//Called when the AJAX response is returned.
function handleSearchSuggest() {
  if (searchReq.readyState == 4) {
    var ss = document.getElementById('search_suggest');
    ss.innerHTML = '';
    var str = searchReq.responseText.split("\n");
    for (i = 0; i < str.length - 1; i++) {
      var suggest = '<div onmouseover="javascript:suggestOver(this);" ';
      suggest += 'onmouseout="javascript:suggestOut(this);" ';
      suggest += 'onclick="javascript:setSearch(this.innerHTML);" ';
      suggest += 'class="suggest_link">' + str[i] + '</div>';
      ss.innerHTML += suggest;
    }
  }
}
```

More specifically the getXmlHttpRequestObject function. it is returning the entire page including my header and footer. I don't believe any more info is needed but if anyone feels that way, I'll supply the view and controller.

https://gyazo.com/d0c43326191a4b09cc4b1d85d67a1bf6
This image shows the console and how the response and response text are the entire page instead of just the results.

Comment: Well you're probably using the wrong GET request URL then... Isn't it supposed to be `suggest.php?search=` (missing the .php) And of course, your 'suggest.php' should actually do a database request and return some reusable data (JSON for example), instead of just outputting HTML markup.

Comment: @Connum i changed that and it gave a different search but still not right. its showing a 404 now and the css that comes with codeigniter.

Comment: I still don't get what your suggest.php is supposed to do and where your code fetching the suggestions from the database and returning them to the ajax request is...

Comment: @Connum The suggest.php is simply a view with the search box and the div being filled.

Answer (score 0):

Your call to the `view` method is loading the header view, the suggest view and the footer view while your suggest model is echoing the data that you're after.

You could just remove the line `$this->view("suggest");` and your suggestions will be echoed.

This isn't great though. I would pass the titles back to the controller from the model then create a new controller method that outputs the data in a structured way (probably JSON).

Comment: I commented out that line but nothing has changed.